# monomorphisms and epimorphisms of local rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ct.category-theory

I want to understand the structure of monomorphisms/epimorphisms in the category of local rings (with local homomorphisms), or dually in the category of local schemes. Let $LR$ denote this category.

- Every monomorphism is injective.

Proof: Let $R \to S$ be a monomorphism and $a,b \in R$ mapped to the same element. Regard $a,b$ as ring maps $R[t] \to R$. Let $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ the preimages of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Then we get two morphisms of local rings $R[t]_{\mathfrak{p}} \times_S R[t]_{\mathfrak{q}} \to R$ which agree when composed with $R \to S$, thus they are equal. Evaluating at $(t,t)$ gives $a=b$. There is a shorter proof which uses $R[t]_{(t)+\mathfrak{m}}$.

2. Is every monomorpism regular? (i.e. the equalizer of some morphism pair)
3. Is every monomorphism extremal? (i.e. $i=ep$ with $p$ epi implies $p$ iso)
4. Is every epimorphism, which is also injective, and isomorphism?
5. Is every epimorphism surjective?

Clearly we have 4 => 3 <=> 2 and 1 => 2. Since in $LR$ every morphism can be factorized as $ep$ where $p$ is surjective and $e$ is injective, we also have 3 => 4.

In the category of rings, 1,2,3,4 are false (see [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like)). However, the counterexamples don't carry over to $LR$. In the "category theory bible" (joy of cats!) you can find nothing about local rings. The questions are partially motivated by Anton's problem about [coequalizers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63/can-a-coequalizer-of-schemes-fail-to-be-surjective) in the category of (local) schemes.

In Lazards article about flat epimorphisms ([pdf link](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SAC/SAC_1967-1968__2_/SAC_1)), there is an example (1.6) in which 4 fails. I have not understood it yet. What is $Z$ there? Perhaps $B$ is a localization of $k[T,Z]$ and not $k[T]$? But I don't believe that $f$ is well-defined.

If the answers turn out to be "no":

- Is there a nice description for the regular monomorphisms? What about field extensions?

If $L/K$ is a finite galois extension, then $K \to L$ is a regular monomorphism iff $L/K$ is cyclic (see Brians comments).

Comment: 1 fails for quadratic Galois ext'n of fields $K/k$ (due to non-locality of $K \otimes_k K$ and how its isom with $K \times K$ is *defined*). In category of local *noetherian* rings, map from ring to completion is an epimorphism (due to Krull intersection theorem, hence the noetherian condition), and in non-complete case provides counterexamples to 2, 3, 4. Doesn't show 2,3,4 fail in $LR$, but kills a reason to care, since affirmative results then seem useless. Category theory is like point-set topology: can get wrapped up in "weird examples"; not necessarily a good use of time. 

Comment: If $K/k$ is a cyclic galois extension with generator $\sigma$ of the galois group, then $k \to K$ is regular since it is the equalizer of $id,\sigma : K \to K$.

Comment: @Martin: sorry, for #1 I got disoriented by Spec and was thinking of co-equalizers. But how about a Galois extension whose Galois group doesn't admit a pair of generators? By restricting to local rings can you find an equalizer pair description for that?

Comment: I'm thinking about that, but it's pretty difficult to start. Even for nice small extensions ...

Comment: @Martin: here's proof of non-existence when Gal. group G for K/k  is non-cyclic. Suppose $s,t:K \rightrightarrows A$ is equalizer pair for $k \rightarrow K$ in category $LR$. Then $A$ is naturally a $K \otimes_k K$-algebra, and by locality of $A$ and structure of $K \otimes_k K$ (using $K/k$ is Galois), the algebra structure factors through projection to a factor field. Thus, $t=s \circ g$ for some $g \in G$. Hence, by univ. property of $A$ and inj. of $s$, any $f:B \rightarrow K$ s.t. $g \circ f=f$ factors through $k$. Thus, $K^g=k$, so $G=\langle g \rangle$. Contradiction.

Comment: The link to Lazard's article seems to be broken; is this (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19282/is-every-integral-epimorphism-of-commutative-rings-surjective) the counterexample you were referring to?  If so, I don't see why $C$ maps to $D$ either.

Comment: Oh yes, this is the example. I'll take a look at Paul Balmer's explanation.