# If the Frobenius endomorphism of a characteristic $p$ ring is epimorphic, is it surjective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, characteristic-p, positive-characteristic, frobenius-map

[MO question 19282](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19282/is-every-integral-epimorphism-of-commutative-rings-surjective) is about integral epimorphisms of commutative rings, and a counterexample is given to surjectivity. What about the case of the Frobenius endomorphism of a commutative, characteristic $p$ ring $R$: if it is epimorphic, is it surjective ?

This comes up naturally when one considers the Frobenius twist functor on $R$-algebras, its right adjoint, and especially the question whether the unit and counit of this adjunction are isomorphisms.

Comment: I take it "epimorphism" is meant in categorical sense? Some authors use it for surjective ring homomorphisms.

Comment: Interpreting derivations $R\to M$ as homomorphisms $R\to R\oplus M\cdot\varepsilon$, the condition implies that $\Omega^1_R=0$. I don’t know if this observation is useful.

Comment: P.S. I remember that in a normal ring $R$, the kernel of $d:R\to \Omega^1_R$ equals $R^p$, so in this case the answer to your question should be yes.

Comment: @Wojowu yes, I mean an epimorphism of unitary commutative rings.

Comment: @Piotr thank you! In fact I think there are many specific cases where one can prove that F is surjective. The general case still eludes me (and I'm not even sure if surjectivity holds).