# Is there an axiomatic approach of the notion of dimension ?

Tags: dimension-theory

There are many notions of dimension : algebraic, topological, Hausdorff, Minkowski... (and others).
While the topological one generalize the algebraic one, the last three need not coincide for every sets. Yet it is generally acknowledged that the Hausdorff dimension has "nice enough" properties to work with (the interest of the Minkowski dimension lies mainly in the fact that it's easier to compute).

So my main question is this : is there an axiomatic approach that would tidy up this mess ? For example, is there a result of the form : if you ask these axioms then the only map from "reasonnable sets" to the set of positive real integers is the Hausdorff dimension ? (or another one ?). If so what are they ?

Are there also a clearly identified list of properties that you would ask from any notion of dimension ? I give the following as an example :

- it should coincide with the algebraic dimension for finite dimensional vector spaces
- dim A $\leq$ dim B if $A \subset B$
- some sort of nice behaviour for cartesian products (at least for reasonnable sets)
- some sort of nice behaviour for infinite increasing unions and/or decreasing intersections

Comment: (The Hausdorff dimention, in general, takes values in the non-negative reals, not only in the positive integers. Having fractional Hausdorff dimension can be taken as a decent definition of "fractal"... )

Comment: my bad, I meant to write positive real numbers of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help http://www.springerlink.com/content/y8l2621113212403/: the author claims to have found the axioms for defining the Lebesgue covering dimension. In the paragraph starting with "the axiomatic problem is an old problem in dimension theory" there is also a list of references that should help. In particular, the paper by Henderson, that would contain the axioms for a notion of dimension in any metrizable space, as an extension of the covering dimension.

Comment: Could you please expand the reference(s)? The link does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer, but there is a surprisingly general generalization of the dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space available in any (braided?) monoidal category. In any such category, there is a notion of dimension of a dualizable object $c$ given by the trace of the identity endomorphism $\text{tr}(\text{id}_c)$. It takes values in $\text{End}(1)$ where $1$ is the monoidal unit and behaves as expected under tensor product. In the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $K$ it gives the image of the dimension in $K$.

Most notably, this notion of dimension includes as special cases several types of *Euler characteristic.* For example, the dimension of a dualizable chain complex (I think this is equivalent to: bounded complex of finitely-generated projective modules) is its Euler characteristic, as is the dimension of a dualizable object in the symmetric monoidal category of dualizable spectra. A nice exposition is given in Ponto and Shulman's [Traces in symmetric monoidal categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.6032), which in particular describes how to use these ideas to understand the Lefschetz fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 5):

There is a notion of "Krull dimension" valid for arbitrary topological spaces, whose definition is totally analogous to that of algebraic varieties, but using lattices of closed subsets instead of rings of functions.

As far as I know, it is the only dimension function $\dim$ defined for arbitrary topological spaces, with the following properties:

- If $Y $ is a subsapce of $X$, then $ \dim Y \leq \dim X $.
- $\dim (X \times Y) \leq \dim X + \dim Y $.
- It coincides with Grothendieck's combinatorial dimension on noetherian spaces, and with the standard dimensions (*cover* and *ind*) on separable metric spaces.

This beautiful idea goes back to the 60's. You can check the following papers and the references therein.

Section 2 of:

- Sancho de Salas, J.B. and M.T.: "*Dimension of dense subalgebras of $C(X)$*", in *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*, 105 (1989)

or the introduction of:

- Sancho de Salas, J.B. and M.T.: "*Dimension of distributive lattices and universal spaces*", in *Topology and its Applications*, 42 (1991), 25-36

Answer (score 4):

My gut feeling is that no list of axioms could simultaneously cover Lebesgue dimension, vector space dimension, Krull dimension, fractal dimension,...

It is  not clear to me, for example, how axioms would decide whether  $\mathbb C$ has dimension $0$, as required by Krull, dimension $1$ as wished by complex geometers  or dimension $2$, the topologists' choice.
(And I haven't even begun to examine the logicians' claim that it has dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$ over $\mathbb Q$)

But this is subjective , so let me say something indisputable: your axiom $A\subset B\Rightarrow dim A \leq dim B$ does not hold for Krull dimension .
Indeed, if $A$ is any domain of Krull dimension $n\gt 0$ and if $K$ is its field of fractions, we have $dim K=0$ and the inequality $dim A=n \leq dim K=0$ is not true.

Comment: So, if the axiomatics work out, we would conclude that Krull dimension is not a dimension.  OK?

Comment: Dear @Gerald, of course what you say is logically correct. And as you may have guessed my position is that since I firmly believe that Krull dimension *is* a dimension, the proposed axiomatics can't work out.

Comment: The Krull dimension works out fine as long as you replace the condition $A\subset B$ by a monomorphism ${\rm Spec}(A)\to{\rm Spec}(B)$ in the category of affine schemes. Or, to put it another way, if $B\to A$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings then ${\rm dim} A\le {\rm dim} B$. So, "subset" should be replaced by "monomorphism" with respect to the correct category.

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb{C}$ has dimension 0 if you look at it in the category of affine schemes (well, ${\rm Spec}\mathbb{C}$ at least), dimension 1 if you think of it as the closed points of the variety ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])$ in the category of complex varieties, and dimension 2 in the category of CW complexes.

Comment: Spot-on comment about Krull dimension, George. 

Comment: @Todd: I should get that one correct, because I answered a question about it a while back (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52197).

Comment:  Dear @George, I agree with your remark on epimorphisms of rings and thank you for the link. But it confirms my feeling that one will have to adjust the axioms to each specific category studied, in a more or less *ad hoc* way (after all replacing an inclusion by an epimorphism in the other direction is quite drastic!). But of course, a feeling is just a feeling, and since I like axiomatics as much as the next mathematician, I would love to see you or someone else prove me wrong and come up with a universal list of axioms for dimension.

Comment: I'd expect the concept of dimension to apply to a category of spaces in some sense. Looked at this way, Krull dimension applies to schemes, giving Lowther's point of view. If you apply it to rings instead, fine (since obviously any commutative ring gives an affine scheme), but this is no longer a category of spaces, so one wouldn't expect the axioms for spaces to apply. So in short, when considering whether a system of axioms validates a particular notion of dimension, find the appropriate category of spaces for that notion and apply the axioms there.

Comment: To follow up on what Toby said: a "category of spaces" in such an axiomatic approach might be reasonably supposed to be an extensive category: see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category . The category of affine schemes is such an example; the category of commutative rings is not. 

Answer (score 4):

In metric geometry, dimension should satisfy the following axioms;
otherwise it should not be called "dimension". 
(There are exceptions, for example Minkowski dimension.)

**Normalization axiom.**
For any $m\in\mathbb Z_\ge$,
$$\dim\mathbb E^m=m.$$

**Cover axiom.** If $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a countable closed cover of $X$ then
$$\dim X=\sup\nolimits_n\{\dim A_n\}$$

**Product axiom.**
For any spaces $X$ and $Y$,
$$\dim  (X\times Y)
\le 
\dim X+ \dim Y.$$

Comment: The "countable closed" bit bothers me for generalizations. Some objects are countable, but still have high dimension in important senses, like $\mathbb Q^n$.

Love the product axiom. It seems essentially fundamental. 

The $\mathbb E^m$ part will be the hardest to generalize. I think a general dimension shouldn't have any axiom of the type.

Comment: For Minkowski dimension the cover axiom holds only for finite union.

Comment: @Will Sawin, it seems like the normalization axiom might be needed in order to have the notion of dimension be unique.