# Catenarity and epimorphisms of rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. The following are well-known:

1. If $R$ is catenary and $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq R$ is an ideal, then $R/\mathfrak{a}$ is catenary.
2. If $R$ is catenary and $S\subseteq R$ is a subset, then $S^{-1}R$ is catenary.

This means that catenarity is preserved along two special kinds of epimorphisms of commutative rings. In view of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/52197) (and its answers) one may wonder:

> Suppose that $R$ is catenary, and let $f\colon R\twoheadrightarrow R'$ be an epimorphism of commutative rings. Is $R'$ catenary?