# Why is the cardinality of the codomain of a ring epimorphism at most the cardinality of the domain?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

According to [this page](http://math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=623) and thence [linked text](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SAC_1967-1968__2__A2_0), if $e : R \to S$ is an epimorphism of rings, then the cardinality of $S$ cannot exceed the cardinality of $R$. This is a non-trivial observation because epimorphisms of rings need not be surjective. Is there a "layman's" explanation of this fact, one that does not require me to learn French?

Comment: If I understand the link to the Stacks Project blog correctly, they rewrote this here :
http://math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/locate.php?tag=04W0

Comment: So...if $R$ if is an integral domain and $S$ is its field of fractions, then $e$ is automatically an isomorphism. That gives an interesting proof that a finite integral domain is a field. Or, maybe, the statement in the question should be regarded as a generalization of this fact.

Comment: @George Lowther : I don't think you are right. Indeed, the injection of an integral domain into its field of fractions is always a ring epimorphism (direct check).

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes, that's what I was getting at. It is always an epimorphism and, if it is an integral domain, it is one-to-one. If $R$ is also finite then $|R|\ge|S|$ is equivalent to e being onto (hence, an isomorphism).

Comment: George, I agree if R is finite, but that assumption was neither in the original question nor in your first comment. In other words : you should really write "if R is a *finite* integral domain etc". Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation of a layman to a layman.
Let $T={\rm Im}\ e$. Then embedding $T\to S$ is again an epimorphism. With respect to $T$ the ring $S$  behaves like the ring (not necessarily the field!) of fractions (compare $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$), so it has the same cardinality. It is enough? :-) I think it is possible to give a rigorous proof by so-called "zigzag-theorem" from Theory of semigroups.

Comment: @Boris: I don't think ring epimorphisms can be described so easily. See this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109

Comment: @George: I tried to explain roughly. Nevertheless Anton Geraschenko in his answer said just about zig-zags.

Comment: @Boris: I see. In fact, lemma 95.11 in the paper linked in Matthieu's comment looks like the zigzag theorem, and is used in the proof of the result asked for here (Lemma 95.13 of http://math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/algebra.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves like" a ring of fractions? That every elemente of $S$ is a quotient of elements from $T$?

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: No,I mean that the elements of $S$ "must" be algebraic expressions of elements from $T$. Don't ask me what means "must" if you want "a layman's explanation"! :-)