# Solid rings and Tor

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, tensor-products, homological-algebra, at.algebraic-topology

A solid ring is a ring $R$ such that the multiplication
$R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \to R$ is an isomorphism.
These were classified by Bousfield and Kan; they are

1. subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$,
2. $\mathbb{Z}/n$,
3. products $R\times \mathbb{Z}/n$ with
   $R\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and
   every divisor of $n$ invertible in $R$
4. colimits of these.

I wonder how small the list gets if I put the additional
constraint that $\mathrm{Tor}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,R) = 0$.

REFERENCE:
Bousfield, A. K.; Kan, D. M.
The core of a ring.
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 2 (1972), 73–81.

Comment: Did you mean Tor_i = 0 for i > 0?

Comment: Is R supposed to be $\mathbb{Q}$ on the second line?

Comment: It seems R must be {\mathbb Q}.  Also, I think you must mean colimits, not limits.

Comment: Your summary of Bousfield and Kan's results is inaccurate in a number of ways.  You should probably start by reviewing their paper.  I think it works out that the only solid rings with $\text{Tor}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,R)=1$ are the localisations $\mathbb{Z}[J^{-1}]$ (for any set of primes $J$).

Comment: I apologize for the mangling of the classification of solid rings; fixed now, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $R^t$ be the torsion submodule and consider the exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow R^t\rightarrow R \rightarrow R/R^t\rightarrow 0$$

Bousfield and Kan show that the ring on the right is a localization of ${\mathbb Z}$, hence flat over ${\mathbb Z}$, so its $Tor$ with $R$ vanishes.  Thus if we $Tor$ the above with $R$, we get $Tor(R^t,R)=Tor(R,R)$.

Now tensor the exact sequence with $R^t$ instead of $R$.  This gives $Tor(R^t,R^t)=Tor(R^t,R)$.

Thus $Tor(R,R)=Tor(R^t,R^t)$.  But if $R^t$ is nonzero then (see Bousfield and Kan) it contains some ${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$ as a direct summand and hence $Tor(R^t,R^t)$ does not vanish.  Thus $Tor(R,R)=0$ implies $R^t=0$.  It follows (B/K 3.7) that $R$ is a localization of ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: This is perfect!