# Quotients of the initial semiring

Tags: semirings

The natural numbers are the initial commutative semiring.  Thus, for any commutative semiring $R$, there is a unique semiring map $\mathbb{N}\to R$.

For which $R$ is this map an epimorphism?

Some examples where it is:

- Obviously, if $R=\mathbb{N}$.
- If it is surjective, e.g. $R=\mathbb{Z}/n$.
- If it adjoins additive inverses, e.g. $R=\mathbb{Z}$.
- If it adjoins multiplicative inverses, e.g. $R=\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}$ (or smaller localizations of $\mathbb{N}$).
- If it does both, e.g. $R=\mathbb{Q}$ (or smaller localizations of $\mathbb{Z}$).

Are these the only possibilities?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like , which in particular answers the corresponding question for $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks; I should go read the Bousfield-Kan paper.  A first question to ask would then be whether every solid ring is also a "solid semiring".

Comment: That should be straightforward; $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphism, and epimorphisms compose.

Comment: Recall that there are other homomorphic images of $\mathbb N$, namely the factors by a congruence $\sim_{a,b}$ defined as $x\sim_{a,b}y\iff x,y\geq a \;\wedge\; b\,\mid\,x-y$. A ring $\mathbb Z/n$ corresponds to $\sim_{0,n}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but is every epimorphism of rings also an epimorphism of semirings?